Which EU countries require EU citizens to register in order to stay there for more than 3 months
Which countries require EU citizens to register in order to stay there for longer than 3 months?(https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/registering-residence/index_en.htm specifies countries are allowed to require this after 3 months).

The answer appears to be further down in the page linked in your question, where there’s a section ‘Find out where and how to register in your host country’ with a list of countries given.

@Traveller, I think you mean the "choose country" button that can link you to some search results for that specific country (Some results of which definitely have very little to do with this question. Others do answer it for that country.)? Perhaps the answers are hidden in there indeed. The fact that for example for Hungary the links are some Hungarian words I cannot read kind of puts me off from looking for the information in those links.

The scary looking Hungarian website actually turns into English when you click on it and contains the answer that you have to register before the 93rd day. That is one down, many to go. I guess that if someone clicks on all the links they can indeed figure out which countries allow this.

In that case, what did you find out when you searched eg “do EU citizens need to register to stay in [country]”?

I’m voting to close this question because the answer is available via the link in the question.

Well I disagree. The answer to most questions is available through extensive research on the internet. Answering that kind of question is kind of the point of this website. No one is doing original research but it still doesn't mean an answer is easily accessible.

If the answers for all these countries is so easily accessible for you through the linked website perhaps you can simply write an answer rather than close it. That seems more useful. (But I think you will find once you start trying that it is actually not that easy to find the answer for all countries and will require you hours to answer.) I'm hoping someone more familiar with these matters will have an easier time answering this than that.

I did try to get GPT-4 to automate the search but it actually got stuck on Bulgaria because it went to the wrong link out of the two given by the "choose country" button. But I still have hopes on a human doing something more clever.
